# Is there anything wrong with my regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a regular expression that will replace odd number of slashes by an even number of slashes while leaves the even number of slashes intact. But for some reason I am getting an error:

```
int matchFlags   = StringUtil.MATCH_SINGLELINE;
int replaceFlags = StringUtil.REPLACE_ALL +  StringUtil.REPLACE_BACKREFERENCES;
String pattern = "(?<!/)/(//)*(?!/)"; //replace odd # of slashes only.
String replace = "$0$0";
RE re = new RE(pattern, matchFlags);
result= re.subst(result, replace, replaceFlags);
```

**This is the exception**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.regexp.RESyntaxException: Syntax error: Missing operand to closure
```

Comment: Please don't use HTML in your questions. Use [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) instead.

Comment: `"odd / slashes /// replaced by // even ////".replaceAll("(?<!/)/((//)*(?!/))", "$1");` works with the normal regex functions. Note that single slashes are also replaced.

Comment: try "[^/]/(//)*[^/]" as pattern and " ".result." " as inputstring and (after replacement) remove the two " "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works fine:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0].matches("(?<!/)/(//)*(?!/)"));
    }
}
```

maybe your RE expects something different

Comment: i didn't deny that; i just wanted to show, that the expression itself is working

Comment: How can I get same result using apache reg exp?

Comment: @Wael : You can't. Read the doc provide in Feysal comment. If you must use apache lib you will have to think of using another way to do this. But as Hashi said with regular java regex the pattern is valid.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you can't use negative look aheads with `org.apache.regexp`. Maybe you should consider use an other lib...

Comment: You apparently cannot use look behinds or look aheads - `(?<!/)` or `(?!/)` - with RE. See [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/apidocs/org/apache/regexp/RE.html) for accepted syntax. You can however use those with Java [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).